# Javascript Functions, Uncaught syntax error, Unexpected token?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, validation, syntax

The following code is giving me an error in the chrome developer tools:

> "uncaught syntax error- unexpected token"

Specifically, the Errors come up in the populate header function at

```
var notraw  = JSON.parse(arrayraw)
```

and in the first if statement, at

```
parsed = JSON.parse(retrieved); //var test is now re-loaded!
```

These errors haven't come up in previous iterations. Does anyone know why?

```
// This statement should be ran on load, to populate the table
// if Statement to see whether to retrieve or create new
if (localStorage.getItem("Recipe") === null) { // if there was no array found
    console.log("There was no array found. Setting new array...");
    //Blank Unpopulated array
    var blank = [
        ["Untitled Recipe", 0, 0]
    ];
    // Insert Array into local storage
    localStorage.setItem("Recipe", JSON.stringify(blank));
    console.log(blank[0]);
} else {
    console.log("The Item was retrieved from local storage.");
    var retrieved = localStorage.getItem("Recipe"); // Retrieve the item from storage
    // test is the storage entry name
    parsed = JSON.parse(retrieved); //var test is now re-loaded!
    // we had to parse it from json
    console.log(parsed)
}
// delete from array and update

function deletefromarray(id) {
    var arrayraw = localStorage.getItem("Recipe")
    var notraw = JSON.parse(arrayraw)
    console.log(notraw[id])
    notraw.splice(id, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("Recipe", JSON.stringify(notraw));
}
// This adds to local array, and then updates that array.

function addtoarray(ingredient, amount, unit) {
    var arrayraw = localStorage.getItem("Recipe")
    var notraw = JSON.parse(arrayraw)
    notraw.push([ingredient, amount, unit]);
    localStorage.setItem("Recipe", JSON.stringify(notraw));
    var recipeid = notraw.length - 1
    console.log("recipe id:" + recipeid)
}
//The calculation function, that gets the ingredients from the array, and calculates what ingredients are needed

function calculate(multiplier) {
    alert("Calculate function was called")
    var length = recipearray.length - 1;
    console.log("There are " + length + " ingredients.");
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        console.log("raw = " + recipearray[i + 1][1] + recipearray[i + 1][2]);
        console.log("multiplied = " + recipearray[i + 1][1] / recipearray[0][2] * multiplier + recipearray[i + 1][2]);
    }
}
// The save function, This asks the user to input the name and how many people the recipe serves. This information is later passed onto the array.

function save() {
    var verified = true;
    while (verified) {
        var name = prompt("What's the name of the recipe?")
        var serves = prompt("How many people does it serve?")
        if (serves === "" || name === "" || isNaN(serves) === true || serves === "null") {
            alert("You have to enter a name, followed by the number of people it serves. Try again.")
            verified = false;
        } else {
            alert("sucess!");
            var element = document.getElementById("header");
            element.innerHTML = name;
            var header2 = document.getElementById("details");
            header2.innerHTML = "Serves " + serves + " people"
            calculate(serves)
            var arrayraw = localStorage.getItem("Recipe")
            var notraw = JSON.parse(arrayraw)
            notraw.splice(0, 1, [name, serves, notraw.length])
            localStorage.setItem("Recipe", JSON.stringify(notraw))
            return;
        }
    }
}
// the recipe function processes the inputs for the different ingredients and amounts.

function recipe() {
    // Declare all variables
    var ingredient = document.getElementById("ingredient").value;
    var amount = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;
    var count = "Nothing";
    console.log("Processing");
    if (isNaN(amount)) {
        alert("You have to enter a number in the amount field")
    } else if (ingredient === "" || amount === "" || unit === "Select Unit") {
        alert("You must fill in all fields.")
    } else if (isNaN(ingredient) === false) {
        alert("You must enter an ingredient NAME.")
    } else {
        console.log("hey!")
        // console.log(recipearray[1][2] + recipearray[1][1])
        var totalamount = amount + unit
        edit(ingredient, amount, unit, false)
        insRow(ingredient, totalamount) // post(0,*123456*,"Fish")
    }
}

function deleteRow(specified) {
    // Get the row that the delete button was clicked in, and delete it.
    var inside = specified.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('table').deleteRow(inside);
    var rowid = inside + 1 // account for the first one being 0
    console.log("An ingredient was deleted by the user: " + rowid);
    // Remove this from the array.
    deletefromarray(-rowid);
}

function insRow(first, second) {
    //var first = document.getElementById('string1').value;
    //var second = document.getElementById('string2').value;
    // This console.log("insRow: " + first)
    // Thisconsole.log("insRow: " + second)
    var x = document.getElementById('table').insertRow(0);
    var y = x.insertCell(0);
    var z = x.insertCell(1);
    var a = x.insertCell(2);
    y.innerHTML = first;
    z.innerHTML = second;
    a.innerHTML = '<input type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)" value="Delete">';
}

function populateheader() {
    // Populate the top fields with the name and how many it serves
    var arrayraw = localStorage.getItem("Recipe")
    var notraw = JSON.parse(arrayraw)
    var element = document.getElementById("header");
    element.innerHTML = notraw[0][0];
    var header2 = document.getElementById("details");
    // if statement ensures the header doesn't say '0' people, instead says no people
    if (notraw[0][1] === 0) {
        header2.innerHTML = "Serves no people"
    } else {
        header2.innerHTML = "Serves " + notraw[0][1] + " people"
    }
    console.log("Now populating Header, The Title was: " + notraw[0][0] + " And it served:         " + notraw[0][1]);
}

function populatetable() {
    console.log("Now populating the table")
    // Here we're gonna populate the table with data that was in the loaded array.
    var arrayraw = localStorage.getItem("Recipe")
    var notraw = JSON.parse(arrayraw)
    if (notraw.length === 0 || notraw.length === 1) {
        console.log("Array was empty.")
    } else {
        var count = 1;
        while (count < notraw.length) {
            amount = notraw[count][1] + " " + notraw[count][2]
            insRow(notraw[count][0], amount)
            console.log("Inserted Ingredient: " + notraw[count][0] + notraw[count][1])
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the JSON you're parsing is not valid JSON. Have you checked?

Comment: You forgot the ; after defining arrayraw

Comment: The JSON is just a 2d array converted using JSON.stringify, In the localstorage, here's the entry:["eggs", 1, "number"]

Comment: The line you cite appears to be missing a trailing semi-colon.  I'm not definitively sure how Chrome handles this.  Some browsers are OK with it and some are not.  Have you run JSLint on your Javascript?

Comment: I ran js lint and it came up with quite a few missed out semi-colons, The error still comes up with the semi-colons there

Comment: If the error says "Unexpected Token o", this means that you are trying to parse an object (JSON that's already been parsed). Try removing the `JSON.parse`, like this: `var notraw = arrayraw`

Comment: If the data is coming from `.localStorage`, it's going to be a string that needs to be parsed. Probably someplace you're doing `localStorage.setItem("foobar", my_object);`, without the `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @user2179936: That's not a fix. Your string needs to be parsed. Why aren't you logging the values you get before you parse them?

Comment: @JECarterII and Eran H.: (Most) Trailing semicolon's are optional in Javascript and any engine choking on this is simply implemented incorrectly (and no major browser does this). However, it is bad practice not to use trailing semicolons.

Comment: @IngoBürk Browsers will screw up trailing semicolons in a limited set of cases, which has to do with the way the spec defines how lines without semicolons should be interpreted. It can be very difficult to understand why those errors would be raised when they happen, which is why using semicolons are good practice.

Comment: @NickHusher I'm not sure why you're telling me this, as it is exactly what I said…

Comment: I was clarifying: when a browser chokes on a missing semicolon, it has to do with a failure of the spec, not a failure of the JS engine.

Comment: I guess we meant different things then. I was talking about this particular line, which even without a `;` is valid Javascript (and any errors would be a problem of the interpreter). But as both of us said, one should always use `;` and then none of this matters anyway.